# Countdown timer in gridview asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, countdown

I have a project table with start date and end date. I want to show a countdown in gridview in asp.net to when the project will end and when it comes to let it display a message 'Project Ended'.

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-countdown-timer-plugin/

Comment: Can you show the GridView code and try to explain better what you want?

Comment: @Asif.Ali I have a script that is now showing my countdown but the challenge i have how do i get an enddate programmatically from sql database instead of a hard coded date using javascript Example: var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2018 15:37:25").getTime();

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to display the number of days remaining for the project
You can do this in RowDataBound event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                DateTime startDate = rowView["startDate"];
                DateTime endDate = rowView["endDate"];
                int daysRemaining = (endDate - startDate).TotalDays;
                if (daysRemaining > 0)
                   e.row.Cells[your column].Text = daysRemaining.ToString();
                else
                   e.row.Cells[your column].Text = "PROJECT ENDED";
             }
          }
```

Comment: Thanks Isol. I have tried it but i am getting an error at                      
                DateTime startDate = rowView["startDate"];
                DateTime endDate = rowView["endDate"]; saying cannot convert object to datetime. I inserted by column name for the EndDate or am i supposed to insert a fixed date inside ["startDate"]. Though  i want to pick the date automatically from my database table